# simplify a python numpy complex expression to real and imaginary parts

Tags: numpy

The expression Exp(it) – Exp(6it)/2 + i Exp(-14it)/3 , for t going to 2*pi is for plotting a Mystery curve as explained in http://www.johndcook.com/blog/2015/06/03/mystery-curve/
there is a listing of python numpy to plot this curve. I want to plot this formula using a procedural language like any basic language. So I have provided this formula to Wolfram Alpha like this:
**simplify Exp(it) – Exp(6it)/2 + i Exp(-14it)/3**
and they output the result as:

1/3 sin(14 t)+cos(t)-1/2 cos(6 t)+ i (sin(t)-1/2 sin(6 t)+1/3 cos(14 t))

so in a basic language I have used this simplification like this:
x = Cos(t) - Cos(k* t)/2 + Sin(14* t)/3
y = Cos(14* t)/3 + Sin(t)- Sin(k* t)/2

The result is exactly the same as python numpy code listed in the referred to page.
My question, how to get the real and imag parts from numpy like we get it from wolfram alpha site?
So it tell us the the real part is Cos(t) - Cos(k* t)/2 + Sin(14* t)/3, and the imag part is Cos(14* t)/3 + Sin(t)- Sin(k* t)/2. or something like that.

Comment: You can't. numpy is not a computer algebra system. If you want results of this kind, you may have more luck with sympy.

Answer (score 1):

```
In [37]: def f(t):
    ...:     return np.exp(1j*t) - np.exp(6j*t)/2 + 1j*np.exp(-14j*t)/3

In [39]: t = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi, 10)
In [40]: t
Out[40]: 
array([0.        , 0.6981317 , 1.3962634 , 2.0943951 , 2.7925268 ,
       3.4906585 , 4.1887902 , 4.88692191, 5.58505361, 6.28318531])
In [41]: f(t)
Out[41]: 
array([ 0.5       +0.33333333j,  0.90203773+0.76256944j,
        0.63791071+0.8071432j , -1.28867513+0.69935874j,
       -0.36142337+0.83291557j, -1.01796187-0.71715012j,
       -0.71132487-1.03269207j,  0.20938564-0.2964469j ,
        1.13005116-1.38903119j,  0.5       +0.33333333j])
```

The result of this calculation is an array with a complex dtype.  That is, the elements of the array are complex numbers.

Basically this is bacause `np.exp` function returns a complex value when given an imaginary argument:

```
In [44]: np.exp(1j*1)
Out[44]: (0.5403023058681398+0.8414709848078965j)
```

It is easy to select just the `real` or `imag` parts of those complex numbers, with `np.real()` or the `real` attribute:

```
In [42]: f(t).real
Out[42]: 
array([ 0.5       ,  0.90203773,  0.63791071, -1.28867513, -0.36142337,
       -1.01796187, -0.71132487,  0.20938564,  1.13005116,  0.5       ])
In [43]: f(t).imag
Out[43]: 
array([ 0.33333333,  0.76256944,  0.8071432 ,  0.69935874,  0.83291557,
       -0.71715012, -1.03269207, -0.2964469 , -1.38903119,  0.33333333])
```

`Out[44]` can be reproduced with:

```
In [46]: np.cos(1) + 1j*np.sin(1)
Out[46]: (0.5403023058681398+0.8414709848078965j)
```

The docs for `np.exp` suggest that this this expansion is being used internally,

> For complex arguments, x = a + ib, we can write e^x = e^a e^{ib}. The first term, e^a, is already known (it is the real argument, described above). The second term, e^{ib}, is \cos b + i \sin b, a function with magnitude 1 and a periodic phase.

But `numpy` does not have any mechanism for doing the symbolic (algebraic) calculation.  It works directly with complex numbers, not algebraic expressions.

---

With `sympy`, a Python symbolic math package:

```
In [1]: import sympy

In [3]: fn = sympy.sympify('exp(1j*re(x)) -exp(6j*re(x))/2 + 1j*exp(-14j*re(x))/3')
   ...: 
In [4]: fn
Out[4]: -exp(6*I*re(x))/2 + exp(I*re(x)) + I*exp(-14*I*re(x))/3
In [5]: fn.as_real_imag()
Out[5]: 
(sin(14*re(x))/3 + cos(re(x)) - cos(6*re(x))/2,
 sin(re(x)) - sin(6*re(x))/2 + cos(14*re(x))/3)
```

I had to use `re(x)` to limit the `x` variable to being real.  Otherwise it would expand the expression to

```
exp(14*im(x))*sin(14*re(x))/3 ...
```